# MongoDB Shard-Key Performance Simple

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, sharding

I have a cluster with 3 config dbs and 3 shards. I am querying against a db with 106M records, each with 410 fields. I imported this data using a shard key of:

```
{state: 1, zipCode: 1}.
```

When I run the following queries individually each one completes in less than 5sec. (SC = 1.6M records, NC = 5.2M records)

```
db.records.find( { "state" : "NC" } ).count()
db.records.find( { "state" : "SC" } ).count()
db.records.find( { "state" : { $in : ["NC"] } } ).count()
db.records.find( { "state" : { $in : ["SC"] } } ).count()
```

However when I query both states using an $in or an $or the query takes over an hour to complete.

```
db.records.find( "state" : { $in : [ "NC" , "SC" ] } ).count()
db.records.find({ $or : [ { "state" : "NC" }, { "state" : "SC" } ).count()
```

The entirety of both states exist on 1 shard. Below are the results of .explain() using the $in query:

```
db.records.find({"state":{$in:["NC","SC"]}}).explain()
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "mongosPlannerVersion" : 1,
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "SINGLE_SHARD",
        "shards" : [
            {
                "shardName" : "s2",
                "connectionString" : "s2/192.168.2.17:27000,192.168.2.17:27001",
                "serverInfo" : {
                    "host" : "MonDbShard2",
                    "port" : 27000,
                    "version" : "3.4.7",
                    "gitVersion" : "cf38c1b8a0a8dca4a11737581beafef4fe120bcd"
                },
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "DBNAME.records",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                    "state" : {
                        "$in" : [
                            "NC",
                            "SC"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "SHARDING_FILTER",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "state" : 1,
                                "zipCode" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "state_1_zipCode_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "state" : [ ],
                                "zipCode" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "state" : [
                                    "[\"NC\", \"NC\"]",
                                    "[\"SC\", \"SC\"]"
                                ],
                                "zipCode" : [
                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
            }
        ]
    }
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

Why would querying two states at one time cause such a drastic difference in completion time? Also, querying a single zipCode without also including the corresponding state, results in the same drastic difference in completion time. I feel like I am misunderstanding how the shard-key actually operates. Any thoughts?

Comment: How much RAM is on that shard primary and what size is the index? Sounds like when you have to scan the full set of records for the 2 states you are exceeding available memory and hitting disk

Comment: @AdamComerford Thanks for your comment. 11 GB is on the primary shard. Running a .stats() on that collection i see a totalIndexSize of 403120128 which I am assuming is in bytes. This would only be 385MB.

Comment: So, should have plenty of memory, looking a little more closely, it looks like the index you are using, if it is the shardkey is going to mean that single states are going to be localised to a single shard (depends on chunk size) because the state is the prefix for the index. Once you add multiple (non-consecutive) states you are going to hit multiple shards. I believe that means the mongos is going to have to collate the results before you get the result, so it could be a limit there (CPU, mem) or you could have a slow shard - needs more sleuthing to be definite

Comment: Hi chanman803; could you [edit] your question to describe the sharding a little more; for example, is the sharding hashed or ranged? And do you know how the shard chunks are distributed among the shards?